# Multiple flames from one mesh

Tags: smoke-simulation

Is it possible to produce several small flames from different parts of the same mesh? I'm modelling a birthday cake with 42 candles, and in a weak moment I joined the cake and the candles into a single mesh (don't ask why, I honestly don't know). I created the candles by modelling one, which I used as a template object for a particle system, which I then converted into objects. Then, ¤#!& knows why, I joined it all, including the cake, together into one glorious whole.

Could I put a smoke domain around each candle, or do I need to separate them? Or could I even accomplish it with a single domain?

I save pretty often, so although I have Blender keeping five backups, I can't recover the individual meshes (my /tmp is a tmpfs, and I've rebooted since the "accident", so no quit.blend either).

Comment: Why not separate the candles from the cake? Try using `P > Separate by loose parts`.

Comment: @gandalf3 Yes, I know about that. But does each candle have to be its own mesh? If that's the case, I'll do it. Or rather just separate the top, including the wick, of each candle. I take it I'll need 42 smoke domains? If so, is there a shortcut to creating that many and placing them on the candles? The candles are randomly placed.

Comment: You can have multiple flame objects in one domain

Comment: @BlendingJake If you can (I don't know if it's possble), I'll mark it the accepted one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate into loose parts like @gandalf3 said `P > Separate By Loose Parts` then have multiple flames in one domain, like this:
[image]

Comment: I'm already there. Setting up the F-curves for some moving objects as we speak. :)

Comment: @BlendingJake - mind sharing that theme? :)

Comment: @GregZaal http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?354395-THEME-Blued&p=2762878#post2762878