# Outputting an STL file that contains multiple objects for import into Blender

Tags: file-format

[NOTE: I originally asked this question on the [3D Printing forum](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/4945/9005) but it seems that it would be more approriate here. Perhaps a moderator would like to move the original question here?

Also: there is no STL tag, but I don´t have enough reputation to create one.]

---

I want to print a object that looks like a flat board with a set of matchbox-like lumps on top of it.

I have written a script that outputs an STL file. To keep the script simple, it creates an object that includes non-manifold edges. To be precise, the board and the boxes are a single model, but each has 6 faces made from 2 triangles. The underside of each matchbox rests on the top of the larger flat board.

If I understand correctly, the top face of the board should be broken up into many smaller triangles to take into account the position of the matchboxes, but coding this by hand (although it might be an interesting Exercise For The Reader) would not be a good use of time, since well-written code that already does this is built into Blender.

However, Blender cannot merge or fuse shapes that are part of the same object. My current understanding is that I will need to:

1. Provide Blender with multiple objects
2. Select all the objects
3. Use Ctrl-J to merge them
4. Export the world in STL format

Is this a valid approach?

If so, my key question is: how do I format the STL file so that Blender will recognize that it contains multiple separate objects?

(I have found references to STL files containing multiple objects, but I have seen nothing in any of the STL files that I have examined that tells me: here is the end of one object and the beginning of another.)

Or should I just be clunky and export two STL files — one for the board and one for all the matchboxes — and then import both into Blender?

---

NOTE: I know that there are free services like [Netfabb](https://service.netfabb.com/login.php) that will correct my simple files for me, but I would prefer not to include that in my workflow if possible.

Comment: if your STL is imported as a single object which has multiple indipendent meshes (not connected) you can import the single object, then easily separate each mesh in its own object, then use multi-obect tools as desired... if they are connected, you need to tell blender which part of the connected mesh is an object of its own, then separate it, repeat. See this to learn how to separate: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#separate

Comment: Aha! Thank you! This sounds like a good path to follow. However, I am a complete beginner to Blender: could I ask you to explain how to "easily separate each mesh into its own object"?

Comment: about method one, you need to enter edit mode, select all vertices, then press "P > by loose parts" (see this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18793/multiple-flames-from-one-mesh) while if they are connected, you need to enter edit mode, select all vertices or faces that need to be a separate object, then press "P > selection"

Comment: Ah. There will be lots of loose parts and therefore lots of fiddly manual selection of vertices. This is something that I will have to do many times, as I refine the shape of the model. I was hoping for a workflow that is as automated as possible. Thanks for teaching me something new!